# Is there a way to keep the alias of the python object being created when appending object to a list?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

EDIT: Context -

I'm generating the code to create a dash application and saving it to a file. I then point my app.py file to pick up the generated code to display the plotly dash app. This is faster then dynamically creating the app because in the code generation process I access a database to get metadata information.

I can solve this by doing the following and wanted to  see if I could avoid this.

`from dash_html_components import Div`

---

I want to make a list of objects & keep the alias used in the import for the objects .

I've tried using no alias to see if I can keep the folder name, that does not work as well.

```py
import dash_html_components as html
test = [1,2,3,4]
ls = []
for i in test:
    ls.append(html.Div('{}'.format(i)))
```

Output:

> "[Div('1'), Div('2'), Div('3'), Div('4')]"

Desired output

> "[html.Div('1'), html.Div('2'), html.Div('3'),
>   html.Div('4')]"

Comment: Is there something stopping you from simply putting `html.` in the format string?

Comment: Looking for a more dynamic solution. This is a simple example, but I have multiple aliases, some of which have the same function name.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Do you need this for debugging? What about objects that already include their real module name in their representation?

Comment: Really looks like a XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Instead of asking help on what you think is the solution to your problem, please explain the _real_ problem you're trying to solve with this "solution".

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, please edit the question to explain. NOTE, what you have is NOT a list of functions. You created 4 objects of type 'Div'. print(ls) (or typing ls at the interactive prompt) is equivalent to print(repr(ls)) which produces a human-readable representation of the object - in many cases it is in the form of Python code that can re-create the same object. This is what you see in your example - the object 'prints' itself as the code needed to create it, but without the module name (because it cannot know what that module is called in YOUR program).

Comment: I'm trying to create a dash application by first generating the code and then using that code to deploy the app. This is a bit faster then dynamically creating the app at load (put the loop to create Div's in the dash app code directly) because I have to extract information from a database. 


One way I've solved this so far by importing each function in the actual dash app 
`from dash_html_components import Div, H1, H2, H3, H4, P`

I'll edit the post as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: no - because the string representation of an object is produced by the module where it lives and that module doesn't know how you imported it.

(assuming that I understand correctly your question).

What you seem to be trying to do is to create some structure of objects (in this case, from the `dash_html_components` module) and then create a Python program that reproduces that structure. It is true that in many cases, `print(some_python_object)` produces a string that is a valid Python expression and that expression re-creates the object when executed. However this is in no way guaranteed and should not be relied upon - most Python objects merely do a best-effort attempt at producing such a string.

In the specific case that you quote, `html.Div("1")` is an expression that returns one object of type `Div` from the `dash_html_components` module. That object's implementation does return an almost-valid "re-create-me" string: namely `Div("1")`. It is the best that it can do - the code for making this string is in the `dash_html_components` module and if `html.Div("1")` were ran in that same module, it would indeed re-create the object. However, that module has no idea whatsoever how it is accessed from *your* point of view. You might have done `import dash_html_components` (then, the 're-create' code would be `dash_html_components.Div("1")`. Or, you might have done `import dash_html_components as h`, then you need `h.Div("1")`, etc. The object's implementation has no way of 'peeking' into your code to find out how you decided to name the module for your own use.

In general:

- if you use `print(object)` (or any other expression that causes `repr(object)` to be executed to produce a string), use the result only for your own viewing / debugging. It is not guaranteed to produce valid Python code.
- if your goal is to generate a Python program, it may be best to do that using string manipulation (as suggested in other answers here).

Comment: - really appreciate the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why anyone would want to do this but you could do it by using a class instead of an import alias:

```
import dash_html_components

class html:
  def Div(*args):
    return dash_html_components.Div(*args)

test, ls = [1, 2, 3, 4], []

for i in test:
  ls.append(html.Div('{}'.format(i)))
```

Or do you mean you want a string array? If so, use this code instead:

```
import dash_html_components as html

test, ls = [1, 2, 3, 4], []

for i in test:
  ls.append("html.Div('{}')".format(i))
```

**NOTE:** you could also use a list comprehension, like this:

```
ls = [html.Div('{}'.format(i)) for i in test]
```

Good luck.

Comment: exactly my thoughts, I think OP needs to give more context on why he would need something like that.

Comment: @JoseAngelSanchez I agree, but it's probably for display reasons, OP might want to save the list to a file or something, either way it isn't something I'd consider doing.

Comment: I'm trying to create a dash application by first generating the code and then using that code to deploy the app. 

This is a bit faster then dynamically creating the app at load (put the loop to create Div's in the dash app code directly) because I have to extract information from a database.

Answer (score 1):

Probably that is not the most efficient way to use dash, if you want to make that list there is really no need to use the `html`

```
for i in test:
    ls.append(f"html.Div('{}')".format(i))
```

then just return it, is this in a `@callback` ?

Comment: You're just hard coding the name- this is not a valid solution to me

Comment: See comment LogicalBranch answer, what OP is asking is really weird and I don't see the reason, he is asking for an array of strings (or just a string?), not `html` objects

Answer (score -1):

From the question what I get is, you are trying to find a way to dynamically add the name of the function variable within your function.

If that is the use case you are trying to accomplish then you can do as such

```
import dash_html_components as html
test = [1,2,3,4]
ls = []
for i in test:
    ls.append(html.__name__ + html.Div('{}'.format(i)))
```

this works because every module object is assigned "__ name __" attribute by default.
Hope this solves your problem.